# Distortion in Image Morphing using OpenCV

Tags: iphone, image-processing, opencv, noise-reduction

I am creating an iPhone application for image morphing using OpenCV 2.4.3. I am able to do the morphing but some noise/distortion is also getting introduced. I am not able to identify where the source of this noise or how to remove it. Please help me out if someone has faced any similar issue or has any experience in image processing. I have attached a sample input/output for reference. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Sample Result]

What I actually need is something like this:

[image: Morph Requirement]

Comment: show some code about how you are doing the morphing..

Comment: Hi rotating_image. Thanks for the reply. I am following this [link](http://engineeering.blogspot.in/2008/07/image-morphing-with-opencv.html) for morphing. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I have modified the image attachment so that you can get a better idea of the 8 points that I am using for the morphing.

Comment: hi, if you got the answer, then please tell me..